# How can I download pip package for other OS?

Tags: python, pip

I'm running on `linux` and want to download pip package for `windows`.

How can I do it ?

For example:

How can I run this command on linux and get the windows package ?

```
pip3 download torch --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument `--platform` to do this. You need to specify as well the `--only-binary :all:` argument to make it work.

Try the following:

```
pip3 download torch --platform win_amd64 --only-binary=:all: --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Platforms are for example `win_amd64`, `linux_x86_64`, `manylinux2014_aarch64`

Answer (score 0):

To download Python wheel packages to a specific location:

```python
python -m pip download --only-binary :all: --dest . --no-cache <package_name>
```

Wheels have a specific syntax for their filename that consists of multiple parts separated by a hyphen which os platform can be specified:

```js
{dist}-{version}(-{build})?-{python.version}-{os_platform}.whl
```

Comment: So if I'm using windows & python 3.8 what is the right command ?